# таймер на jquery

Tags: jquery, таймер

помогите нужен этот код на jquery

```js
  function startTimer() {
var my_timer = document.getElementById("my_timer");
var time = my_timer.innerHTML;
var arr = time.split(":");
var h = arr[0];
var m = arr[1];
var s = arr[2];
if (s == 0) {
  if (m == 0) {
if (h == 0) {
  alert("Время вышло");
  window.location.reload();
  return;
}
h--;
m = 60;
if (h < 10) h = "0" + h;
  }
  m--;
  if (m < 10) m = "0" + m;
  s = 59;
}
else s--;
if (s < 10) s = "0" + s;
document.getElementById("my_timer").innerHTML = h+":"+m+":"+s;
setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: Вот вам в помощь [учебник по jQuery](http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners/), сам по нему учился, думаю вам тоже поможет начать освоение

Comment: учебник не плохой, но лучше документации на официальном сайте не чего нет ( это мое имхо), хотя я не уверен, что он вообще хоть куда-то зайдет ;-)

Comment: @Node_pro, для начинающих официальная документация это тёмный лес :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Моё старое решение на jQuery:

```js
function timer() {
  time_rest = ((time_rest < 0) ? 0: time_rest - 1);

  var hours = Math.floor(time_rest / 3600);
  var minutes = Math.floor((time_rest - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
  var seconds =  Math.floor((time_rest - ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60))));

  if(hours <  10) {
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }

  if(minutes <  10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  if(seconds <  10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }

  $(".hours").html(hours);
  $(".minutes").html(minutes);
  $(".seconds").html(seconds);

  if(time_rest == 0) {
    //location.reload(); // обновляем страницу, если время вышло (скрыл для теста)
  }
}

var time_now = new Date().getTime() / 1000; // текущее время в формате timestamp
var time_to = new Date("21 June 2016 22:33:44").getTime() / 1000; // финальное время в формате timestamp

var time_rest = Math.floor(time_to - time_now); // сколько осталось секунд до финального времени в формату timestamp

// делим на 1000, т.к. ответит приходит в миллисекундах 

timer();

setInterval(function() {
  timer();
}, 1000);
```

```css
  .timer {
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #98001A;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  
  .timer .title {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000;
  }

  .timer .hours, .timer .minutes, .timer .seconds {
    display: inline;
    padding: 1.6px;
  }

  .timer .colon {
    display: inline;
  }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="timer">
  <div class="title">До конца акции осталось:</div>

  <div class="hours">00</div>

  <div class="colon">:</div>  

  <div class="minutes">00</div>

  <div class="colon">:</div>  

  <div class="seconds">00</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дык, ты уверен в своих желаниях? Лови:

```
function startTimer() {
var time = jQuery('#my_timer').html();
var arr = time.split(":");
var h = arr[0];
var m = arr[1];
var s = arr[2];
if (s == 0) {
  if (m == 0) {
if (h == 0) {
  alert("Время вышло");
  window.location.reload();
  return;
}
h--;
m = 60;
if (h < 10) h = "0" + h;
  }
  m--;
  if (m < 10) m = "0" + m;
  s = 59;
}
else s--;
if (s < 10) s = "0" + s;
jQuery("#my_timer").html(h+":"+m+":"+s);
setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
  }
```